# Error when exporting bacpac file from local database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I am trying to deploy a local database to an azure sql databse.
When i use the tool in Management Studio (Tasks > Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database) I get an error when the process starts to export the database. I get the same error when I try to export the bacpac manually. The error is:

> Could not extract package from specified database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> Internal Error: Ese could not be initialized. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)
>
> Internal Error: Ese could not be initialized. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)
>
> Out of Memory (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

A few hours of google searching is coming up with nothing.

I came across a tool called sqlpackage.exe that I am going to try, but I would really like to get this working from the tooling in Management Studio.

Management studio version: 13.0.15700.28
Local SQL Server Express version: 13.0.4224.16

Do these versions matter? Before I go and re-install everything, I assume they are independent of each other?

Comment: I would start by installing the latest [SSMS GA version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). This is especially important when targeting Azure SQL Database. No need to uninstall your old SSMS version as it can run side-by-side too. You'll only need your old SSMS version if you have SQL 2005.

Comment: Yep, works after installing the latest Management Studio. You want to put in an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use [the latest GA version of SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), especially when targeting Azure SQL Database. Newer SSMS versions can be installed side-by-side with older versions. However, that is generally needed only when you need to support old SQL Server versions like SQL Server 2005. The latest GA SSMS version (as of this writing) supports the SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017. The current preview version also supports SQL Server 2019.